# django rest framework update model with image

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to update a django model with a versatile image field via django rest framework without losing the original image? The problem is that the serializer don't accept an image url, just an image encoded in base64.

**About the *"update a django model with a versatile image field via django rest framework without losing the original image"***

I'm referring about the django lib `versatile image field`, I use it in some of my models because I need to give some size options for the images. The proble is, when I first upload a image on the `front-end`, it send an image in base 64 format. But when I'm going to update a model, drf send me the image as an url, so, when the data is posted to the `back-end`, drf ignores the url on the json an delete the already uploaded image.

***serializers.py***

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source = Base64ImageField(source='image', required=False, )
    original = Base64ImageField(source='image', read_only=True)
    crop = VersatileImageFieldSerializer(sizes=[
        ('original', 'url'),
        ('small', 'thumbnail__150x150'),
        ('medium', 'thumbnail__450x450'),
    ], source='image', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('crop', 'source', 'original',)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True)
    variants = ProductVariantSerializer(many=True)
    permissions_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    price = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    sector = CreatableSlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Sector.objects.all(),
                                       required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'small_name', 'large_name', 'images', 'variants', 'price',
                  'description', 'promo_tabloid', 'stock', 'sector')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            if self.is_valid():
                images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
                variants_data = validated_data.pop('variants')
                for key in validated_data:
                    try:
                        instance.__dict__[key] = validated_data[key]
                    except KeyError:
                        pass

                new_variants = []
                for variant_data in variants_data:
                    print variant_data
                    variant, _ = Variant.objects.get_or_create(product=instance, value=variant_data.get('value'))
                    new_variants.append(variant)

                new_images = []
                print images_data
                for image_data in images_data:
                    image = ProductImage.get_or_create(product=instance, image=image_data.get('image'))
                    new_images.append(image)

                try:
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        Variant.objects.filter(product=instance).delete()
                        Variant.objects.bulk_create(new_variants)

                        ProductImage.objects.filter(product=instance).delete()
                        ProductImage.objects.bulk_create(new_images)
                except IntegrityError:
                    return {u'error': u'Failed'}
                instance.save()
                return instance
            else:
                return self.errors
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the line *"update a django model with a versatile image field via django rest framework without losing the original image"*. Also, it would be better to post the model and the serializer code.

Comment: Sorry, I had some issues and couldn't keep to the question. I'll update it.